# Android, NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with method `findViewById()`, it always returns null when using in outside activity class, and i know that i should use this method after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

But how can i use it in my custom button, which was created in xml?

Sorry for my bad english, and this is my first question on stack, amen. (Code sample below)

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<isen.mytestapl.MyButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myBtn"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/textBtn"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>
```

**MyButton class:**

```
public class MyButton extends Button implements View.OnClickListener{

  TextView textView;

  public MyButton(Context context) {
     super(context);
     init();
  }

 public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
 }

 public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
 }

 public void init(){

    setOnClickListener(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
    try
    {
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBtn);
        textView.setText("It Works!");
    }
    catch (NullPointerException ex){
        Log.d("MyLog","NullPointer");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: You can not find views which are outside your component.

Comment: Srsly there is no way insted of using PUBLIC STATIC to get this views?

Comment: Why dont you handle your custom buttons click in an activity class ?

Comment: The problem is you asked a question badly, in broken english (the second is excusable if it isn't your native language, but your mistakes seem to be more not caring than lack of knowledge).  On top of that its a problem that could easily have been solved via Google search for "how to set button click listener android" which would give dozens of examples.

Comment: Yep, its not my native language, and my question is not about "how to set clicklistener".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting the `onClickListener` for your button within the button itself, instead it should be set in the `Activity` that makes use of both of your buttons. Likewise, `findViewById()` in your example can't find the TextView as it's not within the same scope as your button. In absence of code from your activity, here's an example of what you should do:

```
public void MyActivity extends Activity {
     TextView textView;
     MyButton myButton;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

         textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBtn);
         myButton = (MyButton) findViewById(R.id.myBtn);

         myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  textView.setText("It Works!");
              }
         }
     }
```

Comment: And there is no way to rich this views from outside besides PUBLIC STATIC? I though handling click within it self is a good tone, i mean 
Encapsulation etc... whatever i just have a huge project and tryed to avoid do alot of stuff in MainActivity class

Comment: No, [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) in this example essentially means that each object is in charge of itself and should not be inter-dependent on specific instances of other objects. Let's say for example you want to re-use `MyButton` elsewhere, in your example this isn't possible as you have a dependency on an instance of `textView`.

Comment: Likewise, in your activity, you want to override the `onClick` behaviour to fit a specific purpose for that activity. That's why it's better to use `setOnClickListener` at Activity level as you can then create multiple instances of `MyButton` each with different `onClick` behaviours if you so wish.